auto formatting using yapf to put parameters on multiple lines in condensed format
Related to this. But instead of putting all arguments on single line, I want to put them onto multiple lines in condensed form.
Basically I want to transform:
def f(arg1: typ1, arg2: typ2, ..., ...) -> typr:

instead of:
def f(arg1: typ1,
      arg2: typ2,
      ...,
      ...) -> typr:

into:
def f(arg1: typ1, arg2: typ2, ...,
      ...) -> typr:

I tried setting SPLIT_ALL_COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES and SPLIT_ALL_TOP_LEVEL_COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES to false. But it didn't work. Please help.
